# Appending query string through redirect htaccess

Tags: php, string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a rewrite cond in htaccess
I am trying  to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/business/search-results.php?keywords=Animal+Business+Cards&go=Search
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/business/search results.php?keywords=Animal+Business&go=Search
```

or if possible remove the word "+cards" from any search queries...

what I have tried so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^Animal+Business+Cards$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/business/search-results.php?keywords=Animal+Business  [R=301,L]
```

also tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "&go=Search" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

and this

```
Redirect /business/search-results.php?keywords=Animal+Business+cards&go=Search http://www.example.com/business/search-results.php?keywords=Animal+Business&go=Search
```

None of these working... 
is it possible?
Can any one help?
Thank You in advance

Comment: You have to escape `+`in redirect conditions, it's a special character. Use `\+` or `[+]` instead. A `+`means one or more of the character directly before the symbol must occur. E.g. `a+` matches "a", "aa", "aaa" ,...

Comment: @maxhb  umm like this?   `RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^Animal[+]Business[+]Cards$  
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/business/search-results.php?keywords=Animal[+]Business  [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=([^\+]+)\+([^\+]+)\+([^&]+)&go=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?keywords=%1+%2&go=%4 [NC,L,R]
```

Another solution

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?keywords=([^\+]+)\+([^\+]+)\+([^&]+)&go=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?keywords=%1+%2&go=%4 [NC,L,R]
```

Note : Redirect directive does not support querystrings in its old path perameter, that is why your last attempt failed. You can use %{QUERY_STRING} or %{THE_REQUEST} variable to match against urls with query strings.

Comment: Yay!!! this one works!!!! 

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^&]+)&go=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?keywords=%1+%2&go=%4 [NC,L,R]` The other one did not! Thank You so much!

Comment: @User2018878 see the edited answer, Both solutions are working fine on my server now.

Comment: YES YES YES! they are!!!! wow thank you!! it is easily deleting "+cards" from any search query! this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a LOT!

Comment: can you tell me what part in this code is giving the command to remove "+cards"
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?keywords=%1+%2 [NC,L,R]`

Comment: @user2018878 
The first regex capture group **([^\+]+)** matches "Animal"  the second **\+([^\+]+)**  matches  "+business" ,the third **\+([^\&]+)** matches **+card** and the fourth **([^&]+)** matches "Search",  you can see we are not using the third captured value **%3** in the target url. This is how the "+card" gets removed from the target url.

Comment: ah so @starkeen I came up with another problem in which a customer typed 8 words for search ... I used the same code and it worked but how do i make the condition that if the customer types more than 5 words it comes down to 5
I am using this 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^+]+)\+([^+]+)([^&]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?keywords=%1+%2+%3+%4+%5 [NC,L,R]

the above code works if a customer typed 8 words only, 
Thanks again!